# How can i show data in image view parsed from xml

Tags: java, android

i want to create an app Employee details by parsing XML.Wherein the employee details like empid,empname,empcost etc will be displayed .i want to display the images from drawable folder as soon as i get some data from xml. Then i need when i click on each image it shows employee deatils namely : empid,empname,empcost in another activity. 
Following is my java code that shows data parsed from XML in ListView  :

java :

```
public class XmlVdUI extends ListActivity {

    Document doc;

    private Element getChildEle(Element parentEle, String common) {

        for (Node n = parentEle.getFirstChild(); n != null; n = n
                .getNextSibling()) {
            if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
                    && n.getNodeName().equals(common)) {
                return (Element) n;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Iterable<Element> getChildren(Element common, String group) {
        List list = new ArrayList();

        for (Node n = common.getFirstChild(); n != null; n = n.getNextSibling()) {
            if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
                    && n.getNodeName().equals(group)) {
                list.add(n);
            }
        }
        return (Iterable<Element>) list;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        parseXml();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_xml_vd_ui);

        final String _EMPID = "Empid";
        final String _EMPNAME = "Name";
        final String _EMPCOST = "Empcost";

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Element commonEle = getChildEle(doc.getDocumentElement(), "Common");

        Iterable<Element> groupEle = (Iterable<Element>) getChildren(commonEle,
                "Group"); // Iterable<Element>
        groupEle = (Iterable<Element>) getChildren(commonEle, "Group");
        System.out.println("hi");

        for (Element e : groupEle) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(_EMPID, getValue(e, _EMPID));
            map.put(_EMPNAME, getValue(e, _EMPNAME));
            map.put(_EMPCOST, "Rs." + getValue(e, _EMPCOST));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList menuItems.add(map);
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { _EMPNAME, _EMPID, _EMPCOST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.id, R.id.cost });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);

        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

    public final String getElementValue(Node ele) {
        Node child;
        if (ele != null) {
            if (ele.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (child = ele.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                        .getNextSibling()) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void parseXml() {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.root1);
            doc = db.parse(in, null);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

i need to display the images from drawable folder as soon as i get some data from xml rather than in ListView.

Comment: Did i answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to set an [onClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to your ImageViews that will launch the second Activity with the employee info.

If you have any further questions I can expand my answer.

Comment: yes i want onClickListener to my ImageView.The all i want is my images comes randomly from drawable folder as i get data from my XML.

Comment: in simple..... i want to display image on the screen as i get data from xml(image i have in my drawable folder).i need as i am reading data from xml images get displayed on the screen.          onclicklistner is the next step after that .